# Sprin Boot apps no log dir created by running it throgh a remote ssh command

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot

I try to deploy the sprin boot jar file into a remote Linux server and run it throw java -jar command.

The command was much like below:
  ssh  root@xxx.com:/myjdk_path/bin/java  -jar /tmp/target.jar

The problem is that there was no any log dir been created while i running the command.

The sprin boot app was created by the spring.io site,it's a normal app then i put one single line "logging.file=./log/my.log" into application.properties.

But it works(the log dir can be created) when i just logged into the target server and type the command in the ssh console.

The sprin boot version is 2.05 and i've test version 1.5.16 still the same.
And i aslo test it in both Ubuntu and Centos servers,nothing haapens too.

Really appreciate if you can give a clue on this!

---

Thanks all you guys , it turns out my fault, the reason is that I am using a relative log path ,and I run that java -jar command out side the shell directory.

old command:ssh root@xxx.com:/myjdk_path/bin/java -jar /tmp/target.jar

new command:ssh root@xxx.com:cd /tmp; /myjdk_path/bin/java -jar target.jar

the log dir was been created for the old command ,but it in the user home path(for this command is the ROOT user),but not in the /tmp path.
so my stupid check steps missing that point,and thought there is no log dir been created!

Comment: What happens if you change to `logging.file=my.log`? And, perhaps, add `logging.level.root=DEBUG` to the `application.properties`.

Comment: What steps did you use to determine that no log directory is being created?

Comment: Thanks all you guys , it turns out my fault, the reason is that I am using a relative log path ,and I run that java -jar command out side the shell directory.
old command:ssh root@xxx.com:/myjdk_path/bin/java -jar /tmp/target.jar
new command:ssh root@xxx.com:cd /tmp; /myjdk_path/bin/java -jar target.jar